# Why does DATEDIFF wk show 6 days as a week?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was using`DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` to get the start of the week to run a couple of reports, however when it was run on a Sunday it was using the coming week rather than the current week. when I run the following I was perplexed by the results as it shows even though the Day Diff is 6 the week diff is 1 not Zero. Why is this the case?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK, '20160527', GETDATE()) Wks, DATEDIFF(Day, '20160527', GETDATE()) Dys
SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK, '20160528', GETDATE()) Wks, DATEDIFF(DAY, '20160528', GETDATE()) Dys
SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK, '20160529', GETDATE()) Wks,DATEDIFF(Day, '20160529', GETDATE()) Dys
SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK, '20160530', GETDATE()) Wks,DATEDIFF(DAY, '20160530', GETDATE()) Dys
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh6Li.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DATEDIFF` shows the number of boundaries crossed, not an actual difference in time that gets rounded, so that can cause some "odd" behaviors like this depending on when the days fall. As Damien_The_Unbeliever points out, for weeks the start of the week is always considered to be Sunday for `DATEDIFF`.

For example, from Saturday to Sunday will still show a `DATEDIFF` of 1 for weeks even though it's also just one day.

Similarly, from 12:01 AM to 11:59 PM is a `DATEDIFF` of 0 for days, but 11:59 PM to 12:01 AM is a `DATEDIFF` of 1 for days.

Comment: [`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189794.aspx): "Specifying SET DATEFIRST has no effect on DATEDIFF. DATEDIFF always uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function is deterministic." So your example of using different week starts doesn't actually apply.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I'll update the answer to make that clear. I hadn't realized that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I did not realise that it was week changes like from Sat to Sun rather than a count of seven says. Makes much more sense now.